# I want to know how to schedule my shell periodically on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In order to collect aws container resource information periodically, I would like to know how to schedule and execute the shell that contains the collection commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cron which is used to run commands in shell periodically.

[Schedule Expressions Using Cron](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html)